# How do we call the plane a latitude circle is in?

Tags: grids-graticules, gis-principle

I was just wondering if there is a proper term to refer to the plane that contains a [circle of latitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_latitude).

I know for the special case of equator, that plane is called the equatorial plane. What about the circle of latitude for any latitude.

I googled "latitudinal plane" and "latitude plane" without finding anything

Comment: Sometimes the phrase "Great Circle" is used.

Comment: @mschoelen A latitude circle is not a great circle, but a [small circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_a_sphere). OP, I would call it a latitudinal plane, but I don't know if that's an 'official' name.

Answer (score 1):

As was mentioned in the comments, a plane intersecting a sphere through the centre is called a great circle. A plane intersecting a sphere that doesn't intersect the centre is called a small circle. A plane touching a sphere (tangent) would just be a point. Here's the wikipedia page for **[circle of a sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_of_a_sphere)**.

A small circle at a latitude would be a special case of a small circle which may be called a parallel circle. This page on **[planes of the Earth](http://navyaviation.tpub.com/14030/css/Figure-2-3-Planes-Of-The-Earth-40.htm)** explains it somewhat

> The parallels of latitude are small circles constructed with reference
> to the equator.

It is illustrated here:
[image]

You can calculate parameters of a small circle on **[this page](http://www.ambrsoft.com/TrigoCalc/Sphere/SpherePlaneIntersection_.htm)**.

As a side note, in the field of embryology, when a cell splits it is called cleavage. Planes of cleavage (**[defined here](http://www.brainkart.com/article/Cleavage-and-types---Frog---s-egg_670/)**) are called Meridional plane, Vertical Plane, Equatorial Plane and Latitudinal Plane.

> The latitudinal plane of cleavage is similar to the equatorial, but it
> courses through the cytoplasm on either side of the equatorial plane.
> It is also called transverse or horizontal plane.

[image]

Personally, I would call a plane through a line of latitude a "**Latitudinal Plane**".